# How can i eliminate the use of multiple if else conditions in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input form, which user can edit, so on the basis of what user has changed i have to send the data that has changed only, so what i have done is as below, but by doing so i am repeating same lines again and again so i am thinking is there any other way of doing so, phone and email are the string that i get from the back-end and the patientDetails.phone, patientDetails.email are the changed string by the user in the form, so on the basis of that i am making the api calls, thanks in advance any help would be great!!

```
if (editAppointment) {
                const id = Number(queryString.parse(props.location.search).id);
                let editData = {}
                if (phone === patientDetails.phone && email === patientDetails.email) {
                    editData = {
                        datetime: moment.utc(date).format(),
                        id: id,
                        status: status,
                    };
                } else if (phone === patientDetails.phone) {
                    editData = {
                        datetime: moment.utc(date).format(),
                        id: id,
                        status: status,
                        patient: {
                            id: patientDetails.patientId,
                            email: patientDetails.email
                        }
                    };
                } else if (email === patientDetails.email) {
                    editData = {
                        datetime: moment.utc(date).format(),
                        id: id,
                        status: status,
                        patient: {
                            id: patientDetails.patientId,
                            phone: patientDetails.phone
                        }
                    };
                }
                else {
                    editData = {
                        datetime: moment.utc(date).format(),
                        id: id,
                        status: status,
                        patient: {
                            id: patientDetails.patientId,
                            phone: patientDetails.phone,
                            email: patientDetails.email
                        }
                    };
                }
```

Comment: Extract the "static" parts (`datetime`, `id`, `status`) and only add the `patent` property when needed (`if (email === ... || phone === ...) { /*add patent id*/ if (email === ...) { /* add mail */ } if (phone === ...) { /* add phone */ } }`).

Comment: i want to eliminate the if else and use editData object as i don't need the if else condition

Answer (score 1):

You should do it the other way around, ie for each property check if it changed, and if yes add it to the request.

You have three properties which are sent for every request, so you can add them to the object without checking any of the conditions

```
let editData = {
   datetime: moment.utc(date).format(),
   id: id,
   status: status,
};
```

Then check for any of the properties you can edit, if it has changed. And if yes, add it to the request.

```
let patientData = {
  id: patientDetails.patientId
}
let updatePatient = false;

if (phone !== patientDetails.phone) {
  patientData.phone = patientDetails.phone;
  updatePatient = true;
}
if (email !== patientDetails.email) {
  patienData.email = patientDetails.email;
  updatePatient = true;
}

if (updatePatient)
  editData.patient = patientData;
```

This way, you have to look at each property only once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy with it you could do something like this

```
if (editAppointment) {
   const id = Number(queryString.parse(props.location.search).id);
   return {
       dateTime: moment.utc(date).format(),
       id,
       status,
       ...((patientDetails.phone !== phone || patientDetails.email !== phone) && {
           patientData: {
               ...(patientDetails.phone !== phone && { phone }),
               ...(patientDetails.email !== email && { email }),
           },
       }),
     };
   }
}
```

With this approach would would be replacing your if statements with spread operators that spread the data you want into your object when the conditions are met. The syntax can be a bit jarring though